# Why is my app requesting permissions I didn't ask for?

Tags: android, xamarin

my APK is requesting these permissions:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_LOGS
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

I can see that when I try to publish the APK on the play store or when I try to install the APK on my physical device.

However, my app manifest only has:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />
```

Why would my app request the other permissions?

My solution has a Xamarin.Forms PCL project, a shared PCL utilities project and the native Android project.
I'm using SQLite.NET (it doesn't require these permissions) could it be related?

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is the entire manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.SpaceMonkey.Boats">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <application android:label="Boats" android:icon="@drawable/anchor" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: do any of those other projects have manifests?

Comment: @loosebazooka No, they are PCL projects, they are not Android projects.
a Portable Class Library is a portable .NET library

Comment: I recall that compatibility to older Android versions implicitly requests certain permissions. I believe the R/W external storage permissions are due to this.

Comment: @mah I'm targeting min 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to [this article](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/25882/automatically-changes-permissions) Xamarin.Insights.dll manifest have this:

```
[assembly: UsesPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission("android.permission.INTERNET")]
```

Could be this your case?

Comment: I thought you solved it for me, I did have an unused reference to Xamarin.Insights, I removed it, but the problem persists :(

Maybe it's the other analytics library Segment Analytics.NET. I will remove that too and see

Comment: Also, where do you see these lines?

Comment: I found it, it wasn't what you said, but you gave me the right thing to look for. It was the MonoDroid Toolkit package ! thank you very much !

Comment: Great @Spacemonkey !! And that's right. I only show you what IvanGavryliuk write in the forum :)